# Is it possible to integrate clevertap push notification with expo reactnative

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, clevertap

I am using expo 39 SDK is it possible to integrate clever tap notif without ejecting it

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you should be able to do this... However in reality, it may be a bit more complicated. Clovertap is quite specific in terms of exact compatibility without ejecting. It seems that there is little documentation out (at the time of this initial post) for compatibility and use cases between the two systems.

Depending on your underlying problem, another solution may actually be to switch over to FirebaseCloudMessaging.

With that said, lets address the asked problem.

You will probably need to dive into the documentation and attempt code to find out the nitty gritty. I would recommend starting with the push notification documentation:

https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/overview/
https://docs.clevertap.com/docs/push